# Need to identify element on Home Page - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress website for our rugby league team.

At the home page there are two annoying border lines that are in the header but I cannot seem to get rid of them and have tried inspecting element to try and locate it but I just can't.

Can someone please try and point me in the right direction on how to get rid of it

I am using the rookie theme.

[Link to my website](http://uqrldev.comli.com/)

Comment: the link you gave is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.header-area-custom .site-branding {box-shadow:none;}
```